# Why does Swift change the order of unicode in a string?

Tags: ios, swift, unicode

When I concatenate a group of unicodes in a string, Swift changes the order of those unicodes.

```
final_word.append(String(UnicodeScalar(Int(word!, radix: 16)!)!))
```

This code appends to a string the character representing the hex value. If I run it, this is what I get:
[image]

But the circle should come after the word in the order that I appended to the string. However, if I do the same in HTML, this is what I get:

[image]

which is the correct representation. Why does Swift change the order?

**EDIT**: The string used is "\u{fb51}\u{fb52}" and the font is [here](https://quran-1f14.kxcdn.com/fonts/ttf/p2.ttf)

Comment: Can you give us the original string and the string that is appended as text, so we can copy and paste it and reproduce it?

Comment: I put the string and font in the question

Comment: What's the circle thingy then?

Comment: It just shows what verse the text is, so it should come after the words. The circle in hex is "\u{fb52}"

Comment: @Sulthan wow that solved the issue, never knew of this. If you want to add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @OmarHashim I have marked it as a duplicate instead. There are probably other ways to force left-to-right though.